# Read Only Collection

Tags: php, oop, collections

I'm looking for a read only collection in PHP. I've already searched, but i can't find an native implementation yet. I think im  definitely not the first programmer who needs something like this:

My situation is the following: A cart class contains many cartItems. The cartItems should be only editable through the cart (it's Aggregate root). To display these items, my cart needs to return a type of collection. (The items in this collection are already made readonly). I prefer to pass a collection by reference, so the shared collection is always up to date. (even thought i remove/add an item after extracting the collection).

The items are stored inside an ArrayObject in the cart. Is there a native class to wrap ArrayObject to be readonly? If not, does such a Wrapper exists for another type of collection or do i need to write this by myself?

Comment: Why not write an if statement that checks to see if the array has anything in it with empty()?

Comment: OO *private properties* perhaps.

Comment: @Lucas i don't understand your question. My question has nothing to do with determining if the collection contains objects... @ dagon My Collection is private, but i wan't to publish a readonly version of it

Comment: Anything you construct in PHP is only as rigid or as flexible as you write it. To set read only for whatever function or method you use, something like a small check before it runs will achieve this.

Comment: Maybe i wrote my question a little bit confusing... in short: Foo should return a Collection. This collection afterwards hasnothing todo with Foo. Because Foo needs to stay valid, the collection should be readonly

Comment: Why do you need this? You can just **keep collection valid** - do not modify it after Foo returned it.

Comment: I'm not the only programmer in the team and why should the others know, that it's not allowed. There is no sign that this is forbidden... I want to avoid future mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During this discussion i had an idea which solves my problem: I let my cart implement Iterator. So my view is able to display my cart and its items. As results the cart is always returning readonly cartItemObjects. So i never need to publish a collection. Thanks for your participation!

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need to write it yourself, leveraging the `private` type of properties available in classes. This is, I think, the only viable way to go about. Bear in mind that even this is not bulletproof, as you can bypass it using Reflection. Still, it follows the usual adage: if someone wants to break it, they will break it.

Wrap your ArrayObject as a private property of a bigger class, and only allow access to the object through a method of the class (static or dynamic, doesn't matter). This will provide the closest possible match to what you are trying to do, as it will allow you to artificially let reads through (magic method __get() comes to mind) but not writes.

Comment: Of course it is always possible to break the rules, but i want them to know that they do something wrong. Why should it be wrong to change a collection. It's not tagged like this...

My cart already has the ArrayObject as private property. To prevent the collection to be modified i will write my own wrapper... thanks for your advices

Comment: Now that I think of it, you could implement a static function to return a cloned version of the collection. The source remains the same, but you're free to change the returned object as they're no longer linked. Look up the clone keyword.

Comment: Why do you think should this method be static? If it returns a cloned collection, the collection is not up to date if i first extract the collection, edit the cart/its items, and then using it...

Comment: If you want the collection to go through and auto-update on every instance of it, you have no choice, it has to be passed by reference one way or the other. The Iterator you came up with is a relatively good idea, but will not prevent people from directly messing with it (sadly). Ultimately, I think you're hitting one of PHP's limits.